# Which D do I use with choral tenors

Tags: chord-voicings, satb, tenor

I'm writing an SATB choral piece and I want the voices to end on unison D's.  I'm going for a low, rich, sonorous, powerful, truiumphant sound. I'm planning soprano and alto on D4 (just above middle C).  Bass will be an octave lower on D3 (middle of bass clef staff).  What do I do with tenors?

If I put them on D4, they will really project and have a powerful tone quality, but with it being in their upper range it will seem high to the ears.  But if I put them with the basses, they won't likely contribute much.  The sound would be more balanced though, with men in one octave and the women higher.

Comment: To a large extent this depends on the quality of the choir.  Amateur choirs are full of baritones trying to pretend to be tenors (because of a shortage of true tenors).  Professional choirs aren't.

Comment: It might depend on the preceding notes.  Are they already singing higher notes?  If so, a D4 might feel quite natural.  But if they're already down in the bass clef, it might be more natural for them to drop to a D3 than to suddenly jump up in pitch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some tenors can blend well with women's voices at D4.  Others can't.  Some tenors can sing D3 with ease.  Others can't.

Write the tenors *divisi,* or pick one octave and include the other as optional.  Consider adding a note describing the desired effect.  Let the conductor decide based on the individuals in the group.